# Convert the content of richtextbox (TimeSpan) to Double or Float

Tags: c#, datetime, double, richtextbox, timespan

i'm new here, i hope i'm in the right place.
Can anyone help me ?
I have 3 richTextBox in my program
The 1st one is (datetime format) : date start
The 2sd one is (datetime format) : date end
The 3rd one is (Timespan format) : remainning days (from richTextBox1) to next date (richTextBox2).
What i want is if richTextBox3 <= 0 show warning message.
But i Don't know how to convert items to Double.
Thanks in advance.

My code :

```
// Reading Text File 1.
TextReader dateOfStart = new StreamReader (TextFilePath);

richTextBox1.Text = dateOfStart.ReadToEnd();
dateOfStart.Close();

// Reading Text File 2.
TextReader dateOfEnd = new StreamReader (TextFilePath);

richTextBox2.Text = dateOfEnd.ReadToEnd();
dateOfEnd.Close();

// Convert to DateTime 1
DateTime dateStarting = DateTime.Parse(dateOfStart);

// Convert to DateTime 2
DateTime dateEnding = DateTime.Parse(dateOfEnd);

// Calc
TimeSpan remainningDays = dateEnding - dateStarting;

// if richTextBox3 <= Zero, launch Warninng.
If (remainningDays <= 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show (Warnning !!!!!);
}
```

Comment: `dateOfStart` is a `StreamReader`. There is no overload of `DateTime.Parse` that takes a `StreamReader` as an input. Perhaps you should replace it with `richTextBox1.Text` instead?

Comment: Why do you use a StreamReader?

Comment: Change it to `if (remainingDays.TotalDays <= 0)` and see if that works for you.

Comment: In the example above, both `dateOfStart` and `dateOfEnd` are the same thing (they are both reading the file stored at `TextFilePath`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can to do make this work.

First, you don't need to use `StreamReader` objects directly, you can use the static `File.ReadAllText()` method to read the contents of a file into a string variable. This will open the file, read the text, return it, and then close the file for you.

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(startDateFilePath);
richTextBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(endDateFilePath);
```

Next, when setting your `DateTime` variables, you want to pass it the string value, not the `StreamReader` object. Since we've already stored the string in our `RichTextBox` objects, we can just use those:

```
// Note that `Parse` will throw an exception if the text is not a valid date
// Use `TryParse` instead if this is a possibility, 
//     or use a `try/catch` block and catch the FormatException
DateTime dateStarting = DateTime.Parse(richTextBox1.Text);
DateTime dateEnding = DateTime.Parse(richTextBox2.Text);
```

Then, when you do the subtraction, you can access the `TotalDays` property of the `TimeSpan` to get the number of days represented, and set your `richTextBox3.Text` to that value:

```
double remainingDays = (dateEnding - dateStarting).TotalDays;
richTextBox3.Text = remainingDays.ToString();

if (remainingDays <= 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Warning !!!!!");
}
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused, wouldn't it be best to take the result of `(dateEnding - dateStarting).TotalDays` and store it as an int, so you can use it as the textbox value and to save you form having to do a Parse?  Or were those two snippets of code in seperate scopes in your example?

Comment: @maccettura Yes, that's true. I've updated the example. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I would use `TryParse` if it were mine, but that adds a bunch of orthogonal code that isn't directly related to the question in my opinion (adding the DateTime out params, if/else block, etc). There are a other things that could also be done to validate input, for example ensuring that `endDate` is greater than `startDate`. I already made a comment about the `Parse` method in code. If that causes a problem, he can ask a new question. :)

Comment: I didn't even look at the comments in your post code, it must be a monday.

Answer (score -1):

```
double myDoubleValue = Double.Parse(richTextBox3.Text);
```

Incorrectly formatted data will cause this method to throw an exception. Since you are trying to parse direct user input, you should wrap this in a try-catch block. Alternatively, if you are concerned about performance you can use `TryParse`. The `TryParse` method will not throw an exception.

Comment: Wrapping a parse in a try-catch is a lot slower than just using `TryParse()`.  You should typically always favor `TryParse()`

Comment: A. My answer isn't wrong, that is a matter of preference. B. The performance difference would be negligable. C. Try parse requires you to delcare and use an out variable. Plus, Since OP wasn't already doing that, the extra overhead required to do TryParse will just about equal out the loss of efficiency. The user should validate the user input, and throw an exception if something unexpected occurred.

Comment: Throwing exceptions are one of the most performance gutting things you can do, `TryParse()` is around ~36x faster than `Parse()`.  Is a 36x increase "negligible"?  The reasoning is because you don't want to use an out parameter?

Comment: Agree with point `A.`, and definitely not a reason for a down-vote (see ["When should I vote down?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)). But perf isn't the issue here. It's another best practice preference to not use `try / catch` for input validation.

Comment: Sorry, I got distracted when writing my original comment.  The biggest reason for the downvote is because this answer seems to gloss over the OPs code error.  OP is  checking if `(remainningDays <= 0)`, `remainningDays` being a `TimeSpan` object.  Thats the root of the issue I imagine.

Comment: OP didn't ask me to debug his code, he just asked "how to convert the contents of a richtextbox into a double". So I answered his quest, meaning my answer was helpful. Also, he didn't mention that performance was a concern, so my answer is not wrong.

Comment: @MBurnham in that case why should OP even bother putting a body on the question.  You clearly got _everything_ you needed to know from the title right?

Comment: @maccettura, in this case, yes it does some up the body of the question. And the last part of the body reinforces that question that is asked in the title. My answer was not incorrect

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me. Your suggestions works just fine. But when i try ( if remainingDays >= 0 && remainingDays <= 7 ) doesnt work.